# How to move element from one positon in array to another?

Tags: javascript

Using splice funciton?

Now I add element using `arr.splice(i, 1, new);`, But after adding I remove element from last position.

```
arr.splice(i, 1);
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: `splice(i, 0, newElement)` - you *don't* want [to delete `1` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Parameters), after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr.splice(i, 1);
```

That means: Remove 1 Item at the index i. To insert something you need to do it like this:

```
arr.splice(i, 0, "Apple");
```

That means: Delete 0 item at the index i, and insert "Apple" at index i